# How do extension properties act like methods that take a closure and objects at the same time

Tags: gradle, groovy

Assume your build.gradle is very simple, like

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

ext.foo1 = 'bar1'
ext {
     foo2 = 'bar2'
}
assert foo1 == 'bar1'
assert foo2 == 'bar2'
```

This is legitimate groovy but I don't understand why. In the second reference to ext, ext is treated like a method that takes a closure which sets its owner to the instance of ext. Yet, in the first reference, it acts like just an ExtraProperties instance. Using something like:

```
println ext.class.name
```

Actually causes an error because "class" doesn't exist on ext. This might be because ext is a regular object with a dynamically added an ExtensionAware interface, which was added by extensions.create(...). But that's a farfetched, not-quite-reasonable guess.

I don't know how these kind of properties are set up. The documentation is only clear on how property extensions are intended to be used, not how they work or what they are. Can anyone explain?

(1) How does groovy know to go to project.ext.prop1 when 'prop1' is referenced in the build script?
(2) What is 'ext', really?

Answer (score 0):

the following modified script should give you understanding:

```
apply plugin: 'groovy'

ext.foo1 = 'bar1'
ext {
    println "log1:: ${it.getClass()} ${System.identityHashCode(it)}"
    foo2 = 'bar2'
}

println "log2:: ${ext.getClass()} ${System.identityHashCode(ext)}"

assert foo1 == 'bar1'
assert foo2 == 'bar2'
```

output:

```
log1:: class org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension 464908575
log2:: class org.gradle.api.internal.plugins.DefaultExtraPropertiesExtension 464908575
```

means that `ext{ ... }` equals to `ext.with{ ... }`